# Unable to locate element on salesforce lookup window using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, salesforce

Getting error 'unable to locate element' on salesforce lookup window. code used -

```
    Set<String> allWindowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles(); 
    for(String handle : allWindowHandles)
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
        System.out.println("Title of the new window: " + driver.getTitle());
        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//frame[@title='Results']")));
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Camp 2')]")).click();
    }
```

HTML code -

Comment: Please add full exception you get and HTML source code.

Comment: added HTML code in question.

Comment: I was getting unable to locate element error.